# Should not there be "issue" instead of "entertain" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in my "Politics" book which was:

> Several High Courts gave judgements that even after the declaration of emergency, the courts could **entertain** a writ of Habeas Corpus filed by a person challenging his/her  detention.

Now the verb "entertain", in legal context, means "to receive and take into consideration" and the noun "writ" means "a written statement directing somebody to do something". So I think there should be "issue a writ" instead of "entertain a writ(which would imply that court is reviewing a petitioner's order)". Am I right?

Comment: I'm deeply suspicious of the idea that ***entertain*** has that *specific* meaning "in legal contexts". So far as I'm concerned, the relevant definition here is the Full Oxford English Dictionary's 9b *To **give consideration to** (an idea, request, etc.); to **think about, contemplate***. You should understand the text as meaning *The courts could **consider the possibility** of [issuing] a writ of Habeas Corpus*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that in this situation, "to entertain" is closer to "to take into consideration".

> the courts could **take into consideration (writing)** a writ of